# commercetools - multiple catalogs

Tags: commercetools

Doing some discovery with commercetools.  I notice that in the Rest JSON message when fetching a product, there is an element : catalog.  It looks to be an array.  But I have not found anything in the documentation that indicates if there is an ability to have say different catalogs for a given application - For example a Master / Child catalog structure.

So the question is - is there such a thing within this tool?  And if so, how would one go about setting it up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a structural element in the product master data that is a catalog-like concept. It is not implemented as a feature with behavior thoug and the current development plans are not intending to activate this structure for multi-catalog / multi-market / multi-XYZ cases. 
But there are ongoing development activities to improve support for such requirements in in a different way. You best watch the release notes to stay up to date.